# "Recompile with -fPIC" - But recompiling with -fPIC doesn't fix

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

GCC Error:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32S against `ebx' can not be used when making a shared object;
recompile with -fPIC
```

Even when I made sure the -fPIC flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to compile a file that includes inline assembly, make sure you're not missing a **%** sign before a register.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use -fPIC on the linker line.  Sometimes templates get compiled by the linker.

Answer (score 0):

That error message should say "without -fPIC".